# ggvis dynamic/interactive plots in a knitr document

Tags: r, knitr, ggvis

I am wondering if somebody has been able to get a dynamic [ggvis](/questions/tagged/ggvis) plot to work with a [knitr](/questions/tagged/knitr) document.  I am getting the following warning when I produce my plot and the interactive tool tip does not work after using `knitr`.

> Warning: Can't output dynamic/interactive ggvis plots in a knitr
>   document. Generating a static (non-dynamic, non-interactive) version
>   of the plot.

```
df %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  ggvis(~Week,~Rank, stroke = ~Team) %>%
  layer_points(size := 40, size.hover := 200, fill = ~Team, key:=~id) %>%
  layer_lines(stroke.hover = ~Team, strokeWidth.hover := 8, strokeWidth := 1) %>%
  add_axis("x", title="Week",  subdivide = 0, values = seq(1, 17, by = 1), format="####") %>%
  add_axis("y", title="Rank", subdivide = 0, values = seq(1, 10, by = 1), format='####') %>%
  scale_numeric("y", reverse=TRUE) %>%
  add_tooltip(all_values, "hover")
```

Everything works after I knit the `.Rmd` file except for `add_tooltip()`

Comment: Did you try updating to the latest version of Rstudio/R? There was another SO question where that solved the issue, although that person was getting a different message than you are.

Comment: @MaxPower link to question?